# Meaning of  a Logical Operator

Tags: logic, terminology

Is it possible to know what those operator mean if they must be involved in this logicical condition?
What is all the possible meaning of those two symbol if you don't know the symbol's meaning beforehand:
(¬A) ⊕ A is always true, A ⊕ A is always false and with just those definition given, others unknown

If it is not possible to get the outcome, how to prove it is insuffient?

Comment: Insufficient data for meaningful answer.

Comment: How to prove this is insufficient?

Comment: Are you talking about $¬$ and $⊕$? You can look up logic symbols in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logic_symbols).

Comment: No, i think it could be of great useful example if you could prove it insufficient to get the outcome

Comment: @PeterT.off I don't think it is insufficient. "Given two rules specifying the operation of ⊕, find ⊕": that's a legitimate question. See my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on the description *given in the question,* we can build the following truth table:
$$
\begin{matrix}
A & A & | & ⊕ \\
\hline
F & F & | & F & \color{red}{\text{A ⊕ A}}\\
F & T & | & T & \color{blue}{\text{¬A ⊕  A}}\\
T & F & | & T & \color{blue}{\text{A ⊕ ¬A}}\\
T & T & | & F & \color{red}{\text{A ⊕ A}} \\
\end{matrix}
$$
Now, we can deduce $⊕$ is the *exclusive or* operation. Deduced directly from the rules stated in the question.

---

**Addednum:** We can easily deduce the meaning of $\neg.$ Given the set $\mathbb{B} = \{ T, F \},$ any *unary* operator $\neg : \mathbb{B} \to \mathbb{B}$ will either operate as identity
 or as negation. Since the 2 equations in the given problem differ only by $\neg,$
$$ A \oplus \neg A = T, A \oplus A = F, $$
we can deduce that $\neg$ can not be identity (assume $\neg A \equiv A$ and you'll get contradiction in the given system of formulas). Hence $\neg$ is negation. QED. Now we proceed as above.

Comment: i mean you don't even know the other symbol ¬ mean beforehand...

Comment: @Victor I can easily deduce the meaning of $\neg.$ Given the set $\mathbb{B} = \{ T, F \},$ any **unary** operator $\neg$ will either operate as identity or as negation. Since the 2 equations in the given problem differ only by $\neg,$ I can deduce that $\neg$ can not be identity, i.e., it is negation.

Comment: @PeterT.off I've just posted a comment above this one answering this very same question.